# Pine script request.security issue

Tags: pine-script, crossover

Been learning a lot from here and finally putting in my first post.  I am building a custom TradingView plotshape for a 1 hour crossover on a 15 min chart and getting an error.  I'm hoping someone can help me address this.

```
src1 = request.security(syminfo.ticker, '60', ta.rsi(close, 14))
src2 = request.security(syminfo.ticker, '60', ta.sma(close, 14))
(line 13)rsi = ta.rsi(close, src1)
(line 14)sma = ta.sma(rsi, src2)
crossover = ta.crossover(rsi, sma)
```

Here is the error when saving -

> line 13: Cannot call 'ta.rsi' with argument 'length'='src1'. An
> argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'simple int' is
> expected line 14: Cannot call 'ta.sma' with argument 'length'='src2'.
> An argument of 'series float' type was used but a 'series int' is
> expected

Comment: Why are you using `src1` and `src2` in line #13 and #14 respectively?

Comment: Because I’m looking to get RSI and SMA data from the requested security. Is that not correct?

Comment: What I meant is why are you using `src1` in this `ta.rsi(close, src1)` call?

Comment: I am applying this to a 15 min chart and it's requesting the hour info.  I called it out as SRC for no real reason.  What am I doing wrong?